# Error in IntelliJ to update maven repo: Repository is non-nexus or does not indexed

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nexus

I am not sure I understand what this error refers to.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using oss.sonatype.org repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what finally worked for me:

```
// delete .m2 folder and then try following replace below
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots -> https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/
```

Comment: where did you do that replace exactly?

Comment: replace in pom file